# iPhone style listViews for Cocoa/Monomac

Tags: cocoa, mono, monomac

The iPhone has some really nice ways of creating listViews with custom cells. Is there any similar thing for CocoaOSx or Monomac? I am using both to create a set of apps and would like to create nice iPhone style listViews like those in the Twitter app and the Sparrow app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but check if PXListView would work.

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/mac-os-x/controls/pxlistview

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the new view-based NSTableView in Lion, depending on what kind of "iPhone-like" you're after.